# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn with CSV File

Tags: c#, wpf

Rebuilding a project in WPF for Binding oh CSv files. I have a csv file that I am importing and I only need 3 of its columns. That I have working perfect. I will then have columns added to the datagrid and each one needs to be a combobox. Only thing is the static list I need will be used in each of the columns that are added. I have created my datagrid and able to get the rows i need from the csv file at column 0,1,11 off the csv file. I can create the DataGridComboBoxColumn but I can not get any data in it. The static data will be as follows "7:00a, 8:00a all the way up to 6:00a"
Then from there I need to save that csv layout to be recalled as a import to the datadrid.

My xaml code

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="EmpList" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpList}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              AlternatingRowBackground="PowderBlue" Padding="120,20" Background="Gray">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=EmpName}" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payroll ID" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=EmpPayrollID}" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=JobName }" Width="110"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Monday" 
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=StreetAddress}"  />
            
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

and my class code:

```
    class GetCsvEmp
{

    public List<EmpCsvGet> EmpList { get; set; } = GetEmpget();
    public static List<EmpCsvGet> GetEmpget()
    {
        var file = @"c:\rcs\export\timecard.csv";
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        var list = new List<EmpCsvGet>();
       // EmpCsvGet.InsertRange(12, new string[] { "Mahesh Beniwal", "Chand Beniwal", "Mahesh Chand Beniwal" });
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = lines[i].Split(',');
            var empCsvGet = new EmpCsvGet()
            {
                EmpName = line[0],
                EmpPayrollID = line[1],
                JobName = line[11]
                //Monday = line[3]

            };
            list.Add(empCsvGet);
            
            
           

        };
        return list;
    }
}


public class EmpCsvGet
{

    // [Index(0)]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    //  [Index(1)]
    public string EmpPayrollID { get; set; }
      //[Index(11)]
    public string JobName { get; set; }
 
    public string Monday { get; set; }
    
    

}
```

Updated for the static data.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

public ObservableCollection<string> TimeIn { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> TimeOut { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
{
  TimeIn = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "7:00a", "8:00a", "9:00a", "10:00a", "11:00a", "12:00p", "1:00p", "2:00p", "3:00p",
      "4:00p", "5:00p", "6:00p", "7:00p", "8:00p", "9:00p", "10:00p", "11:00p", "12:00a", "1:00a", "2:00a", "3:00a", "4:00a" };


  TimeOut = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "7:00a", "8:00a", "9:00a", "10:00a", "11:00a", "12:00p", "1:00p", "2:00p", "3:00p",
      "4:00p", "5:00p", "6:00p", "7:00p", "8:00p", "9:00p", "10:00p", "11:00p", "12:00a", "1:00a", "2:00a", "3:00a", "4:00a" };



        InitializeComponent();
        MonIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        MonOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;

        TuesIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        TuesOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;

        WedIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        WedOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;

        ThurIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        ThurOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;

        FriIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        FriOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;

        SatIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        SatOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;

        SunIn.ItemsSource = TimeIn;
        SunOut.ItemsSource = TimeOut;


        
    }
```

Comment: *"The static data will be as follows "7:00a, 8:00a all the way up to 6:00a"...* So where do you create this data?

Comment: Added the static data code.